# changing selected state of fetched item from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API that returns me arrays. I implemented the code to search 3 of them like this:

```
{response !== undefined &&
        search !== "" &&
        response.InsuranceServiceList.filter((insurance) =>
          insurance.Name.replace(/ي/g, "ی", /ا/, "آ").includes(search)
        )
          .slice(0, 3)
          .map((filtered, i) => (
            <EachInsurance
              filtered={filtered}
              key={i}
              styles={scss}
              DatePresence={DatePresence}
              IdInsurance={IdInsurance}
              TimePresence={TimePresence}
            />
          ))}
```

whenever user types something in search box, 3 of these matching arrays will get rendered.

but I have two problems with selecting them.

this is each insurance component:

```
<Container
      className={styles.eachInsurance}
      style={{
        borderRight: `${selectInsurance ? "20px" : "1px"} solid #fcc4de`,
      }}
    >
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectInsurance((prev) => !prev);
          setCount(0);
        }}
      >
        <p className={styles.NameService}>{filtered.Name.replace(/ي/g, "ی")}</p>
      </div>
   </Container>
```

whenever user clicks on element. it will have pinkish border with the width of 20px.

the problem is, when I type another thing to search another item. it shows that Item selected.

just like the clicked div is still there but the content inside of it has changed.

how can I prevent this problem?

I thought it would render a new `div` per each array. but it wasn't.

the second problem is search itself. if you delete what you've write completely (emptying search bar). everything you have selected before will get removed and you will need to reselect it again.

I want to prevent this too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id from your back end to your front end. then add a border based on the ids you pass to the `selectInsurance`, in that way you will know if the element change the border will be gone.
I think for your second problem you can add a new state that will reserve the whole object of the insurance and you first render from that array so every time you re-render your search array your selected insurance array will stay the same so they will remain in your page

Comment: but I have one Id per each element. I have nothing to compare with it. like saying react that if this Id is equals to that Id. select this specific element.

Comment: select insurance is just a simple state like this:                                                                   `const [selectInsurance, setSelectInsurance] = React.useState(false); `

Comment: I think you need to control your selected insurance through your HOC. I mean you have the IdInsurance you can use this and pass it to an array in your HOC and based on that array check if you need to add 20px or not

Comment: but I use function component. HOC is only available in class components, isn't it? I don't know how to implement it to function component

Comment: I don't know which version of react you are using but lately, they create a hook called [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and you can use this to create states you need inside your functional component and working with it is very easy.